# file uploading Django code not working from /var/www/

Tags: django

```
def upload(request):
    print(request.FILES)
    if request.POST and request.FILES:
        files = request.FILES
        print(files)

        for file in files:
            data = files[file]
            with open('/tmp/%s' % data.name, 'wb+') as dest:
                for chunk in data.chunks():
                    dest.write(chunk)
        return render(request, "create.html")

    return HttpResponse("Failed to Upload")
```

Above code works from when Django project is in the root folder, but when I push the code to /var/www/ folder the same code not working.

For request.FILES I am not getting the files uploaded in the output.`<MultiValueDict: {}>`

Not able to understand where the code is missing.

Can anyone help me out finding out what is the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Comment: <form action="{% url "upload" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="bmcs_key">BMCS KEY: </label><input type="file" value="bmcs_key"><br>
    <label for="ssh_key">SSH KEY: </label><input type="file" value="ssh_key"><br>
    <label for="provider">provider: </label><input type="file" value="provider"><br>
    <label for="tenant_name">Tenant Name: </label><input type="text" name="tenant_name"><br>
    <label for="username">User Name: </label><input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

Comment: the above code is my index.html file

Comment: Add that to your question rather than a comment. It will be easier to read =)

Comment: above code is working if I have sample project in my root folder. but it is not working if it is placed in /var/www/ folder

Comment: Are you using development server or web server to serve the requests?

Comment: currently development server. I have already wrote code to run on web server on httpd.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{% url "upload" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="bmcs_key">BMCS KEY: </label><input type="file" value="bmcs_key"><br>
    <label for="ssh_key">SSH KEY: </label><input type="file" value="ssh_key"><br>
    <label for="provider">provider: </label><input type="file" value="provider"><br>
    <label for="tenant_name">Tenant Name: </label><input type="text" name="tenant_name"><br>
    <label for="username">User Name: </label><input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

after adding name attribute in input tag code worked.

Comment: <input type="file" name="bmcs_key">